# Why is the AVCaptureVideoDataOutput callback dependent on the OpenGL draw framerate?

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, camera, avcapturesession

When looking at the [GLCameraRipple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GLCameraRipple/Introduction/Intro.html) example, the AVCaptureVideoDataOutput is setup in such a way that a callback is called (captureOutput) whenever a new frame arrives from the iphone camera.

However, putting a "sleep(1)" at the beginning of the "drawInRect" function (that is used for OpenGL drawing), this callback gets called only 1 time per second, instead of 30 times per second.

Can anyone tell me why the framerate of the iphone camera is linked with the framerate of the OpenGL draw call?

---

Update: Steps to reproduce

- Download the GLCameraRipple sample from here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GLCameraRipple/Introduction/Intro.html
- In RippleViewController.m => captureOutput, add a 
  `NSLog(@"Got Frame");`. Running it will generate a lot of "Got Frame" messages (about 30 per second)
- In RippleViewController.m => drawInRect, add a `sleep(1);` at the very beginning of the function. Only one message per second appears now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When AVCaptureVideoDataOutput call delegate method captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection: to make programer able to edit or record image from camera, this method called from main thread. and, normally we should program the code that interact with user interface directly by main thread and that why OpenGL liked with AVCaptureVideoDataOutput because method from camera and draw to screen are run in main thread.

and AVCaptureVideoDataOutput class can drop the image if iPhone cannot process the captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection: finished in time like the process time more than 1/30 second next frame will be ignore that you can collect the data with captureOutput: didDropSampleBuffer: fromConnection: method

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! How do you know this? (Especially that the camera callback runs in the main thread). Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: @JanRüegg - They are correct that this is being called on the main thread, but that's because Apple explicitly put it on the main queue using this line: `[dataOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];`. It can be placed on background queues, if you like, but then you have to worry about building up blocks in that queue if your rendering doesn't keep up with the incoming video frame rate. Sunama is incorrect in stating that OpenGL rendering must be done on the main thread, because it can be done in the background as long as multiple threads don't access a context.

Comment: Hmm... I tested it and I have the same problem when i use this line: `[dataOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)];` Shouldn't the global queue be running in another thread?

Comment: it should be [dataOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:dispatch_queue_create("Some Queue", NULL)];

Comment: This leads to an EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash. Did you test your proposed solution? I added more information to the question about how to reproduce the problem...